# Using rest api for fetching data from iserver on SharePoint page

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online

I have one task to fetch the data from iServer to SharePoint page using rest. I  am getting the error:

> 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED'.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    EventsCalenderfunc();
  });

  function EventsCalenderfunc() {
    $.ajax
      ({
        url: "https://{iserver URL}/_api/web/items",
        type: 'GET',
        data: JSON,
        headers:
        {
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
          "IF-MATCH": "*",
          "X-HTTP-Method": null
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
            var item = data.d.results[i];
            console.log(item);
          }
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log('Something is wrong');
        }
      });
  }
</script>
```

In  console I am getting the output 'Something is wrong' and the error described above.

Comment: Thanks, will keep that in mind.

Comment: What is 'iserver'? Is it SharePoint server? If so, there is no `/_api/web/items` endpoint. Also you have GET request so using object `data` is irrelevant same as headers `Content-Type, IF-MATCH and X-HTTP-Method`.

Comment: iServer is the product of orbus software and is like SharePoint(Library etc).